# Warning: You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine

For a school Project I built an API in Unity. While doing so, the following Warning occurred:

> You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
> UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()

I have no GameObject. It is a script that should serve a pure interface. Below is my code. Can someone help me?

```
public class ApiPost : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool PostDataSchachtGui(string url,string SchachtNrGui)
    {
        bool isfinish = false;

        var instance = new ApiPost();
        instance.StartCoroutine(Post(url, SchachtNrGui));

        IEnumerator Post(string uri, string schacht_nr)
        {
            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            form.AddField("SchachtNr1", schacht_nr);

            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, form);
            www.chunkedTransfer = false;

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                isfinish = false;
            } 
            else
            {
                isfinish = true;
            }
        }
        return isfinish;
    }
}
```

```
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void abfragen(string button)
    {
        if (button == "start")
        {
            StartBtn.postdata();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void postdata()
{
    //Suche Inputfeld
    GameObject Schacht_field = GameObject.Find("Schacht_field");
    input Schacht = Schacht_field.GetComponent<input>();
    SchachtNrGui = Schacht.inputtext;
    //Setze Globale Daten
    StaticData.SchachtNrDataShow = SchachtNrGui;
    //Poste Daten
    var check = ApiPost.PostDataSchachtGui("http://localhost/prototype1/setumgevar.php", SchachtNrGui);
    if (check == true)
    {
        //ApiGet.GetAllData("http://localhost/prototype1/getdata.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with the line that reads `var instance = new ApiPost();`.

Your class `ApiPost` inherits from `Monobehaviour` and like the error states, you are not allowed to create a `MonoBehaviour` using the `new` keyword, but you can  add MonoBehaviours via the AddComponent() Method.

You have two primary courses of actions

1. Remove the inheritance from `Monobehaviour` in your first line. Instead of `public class ApiPost : MonoBehaviour` just use `public class ApiPost`.
2. Restructure the base of your code to create your `ApiPost` instance in a different way. You can `Instantiate` the object it is attached to, `GetComponent` the object, or a different Method. For example you could access by attaching `ApiPost` to `ApiGameObject` and then call:

   ```
   var instance = ApiGameObject.GetComponent<ApiPost>();
   ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific with the question? What is the enum here?

If you are talking about `ApiPost`, then yes, you can't instantiate a MonoBehaviour like that. You have to attach that script to a GameObject, then reference that GameObject in your script. Then using that gameobject, you access your script with GetComponent().

So something like this:

```
//write this in your class
public GameObject myGameObject;

//write this in your function:
var instance = myGameObject.GetComponent<ApiPost>();
```